# Path conflict in Qt Creator

Tags: qt4, qt-creator

On building a project on Qt Creator, I get an error:

```
Failure to read QMAKESPEC conf file /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf.
Error processing project file: /path/to/my/project/directory/project.pro
01:13:32: The process "/usr/bin/qmake-qt4" exited with code 3.
Error while building/deploying project converter (kit: Qt 4.8.4 in PATH (System))
When executing step 'qmake'
```

But when I executed

```
locate qmake.conf
```

on terminal, I found that the file was located at

```
/usr/lib64/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf
```

How do I configure Qt Creator to consider the correct path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and run `qmake` with `-spec` parameter

```
$qmake -spec /usr/lib64/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf *.pro
```

Or you can create a symbolic link to your new file at the location of the old file (that would make a permanent solution)

```
#ln -s /usr/lib64/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf
```

Or you can set environment variable `QMAKESPEC` to corespond to the new value

```
QMAKESPEC = /usr/lib64/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf
export QMAKESPEC
```

To make it permanent add it to your `.bashrc` (or whichever shell you're using)